# SQLiteOpenHelper not updating the DB even after DB version changed & uninstalled the Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am stuck with my SQLiteOpenHelper class.
I created a DB and all my data from DB is on the app.
But later I added one column in one of the tables and now it says `no such column` in that table.
I have updated the DB version and also uninstalled the app and installed it again after updating the DB version, but it still shows the same issue: `no such column` exists.

If I comment Column:type, then it says `no such column named desc`

I recreated the whole DB structure in a new file but still stuck in same issue.

Help me out, guys!

```
public static final String TABLE_RESTAURANTS = "restaurants";
public static final String COLUMN_LID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_LNAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_LDESC = "desc";
public static final String COLUMN_LTYPE = "type";
```

In onCreate

```
String CREATE_TABLE_RESTAURANTS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RESTAURANTS + "("
            + COLUMN_LID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_LNAME + "TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_LDESC + "TEXT," + COLUMN_LTYPE + "TEXT" + ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_RESTAURANTS);
```

In onUpgrade

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_RESTAURANTS);
onCreate(db);
```

Insertion method

```
public void insertRestaurantItsms(AppetiserData cartData)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_LNAME, cartData.getName());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_LDESC, cartData.getDescription());
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_LTYPE, cartData.getCategory());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_RESTAURANTS, null, contentValues);

    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Fetch method

```
 public List<AppetiserData> getAllDatarl(){
    List<AppetiserData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RESTAURANTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            AppetiserData data = new AppetiserData();

            data.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            data.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));

            // Adding data to list
            dataList.add(data);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: Wherever you have this type of string concatenation, do not forget to add <SPACE> before the concated string. eg.: ...EXISTS<space>"+ TABLE_RESTAURANTS..., COLUMN_LNAME + "<space>TEXT,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off course you had missed the space and you have also missed to put the semi-colon at the end of the query. Below I have added those changes to your query and posted.

**Create Table Query:**

```
String CREATE_TABLE_RESTAURANTS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_RESTAURANTS + " ( "
            + COLUMN_LID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_LNAME + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_LDESC + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_LTYPE + " TEXT " + ");";
```

**Drop Table:**

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_RESTAURANTS);
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: `you have also missed to put the semi-colon at the end of the query`... which is **absolutely useless**.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> String CREATE_TABLE_RESTAURANTS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RESTAURANTS + "("
>         + COLUMN_LID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_LNAME + "TEXT,"
>         + COLUMN_LDESC + "TEXT," + COLUMN_LTYPE + "TEXT" + ")";
> ```

You need spaces between column names and their types to not get columns like `descTEXT`.

> ```
> db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_RESTAURANTS);
> ```

You need space between `EXISTS` and the table name. If this SQL was ever executed, you would have seen an exception about the syntax.

Comment: That what I did or U mean something like COLUMN_LNAME + "TEXT, "